# Keeping track of used memory with overloaded new and delete operator?

Tags: c++

Ok guys so my goal is track the memory that has been allocated. In order to do so I created a static variable and overloaded new and delete operators. I'm bit confused though. When I create new int object it allocates 4 bytes of memory, however when I delete the pointer to this int it says that 8 bytes has been deleted. Is there a way to track it accurately? Further down the road I would also like to track dynamically created objects and track how much memory has been used for it.
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

static int memory{0};

void* operator new(std::size_t sz){
    memory+= sz;
    return std::malloc(sz);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept{
    memory-= sizeof(ptr);
    std::free(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    int * p = new int;
    *p = 2;
    std::cout << memory; // memory = 4

    delete p;
    std::cout << memory; // memory = -4 
}
```

Comment: That's probably a race condition. Try the same with an atomic variable for the memory.

Comment: sizeof(ptr) is not the amount you allocated but the size of a pointer (8 bytes on x64)

Comment: @davidhigh: there's only one thread.

Comment: You can allocate more to save size near of returned pointer. Care with alignment.

Comment: Try overload (5) in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Comment: @RichardCritten: Read the explanation below. Overload 5 is an optional, additional overload, intended to add some efficiency to specific cases. You can't rely on it.

Comment: `sizeof(ptr)` gives the size of the pointer itself.   It doesn't give the size of what the pointer points at (i.e. the memory allocated by `operator new()`).  If `sizeof(void *) == 8` (consistent with a 64-bit system) and `sizeof(int) == 4`, that will explain the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit annoying, isn't it? `free` knows how much memory there is to free, but won't tell you.

The practical solution is to add an extra `sizeof(size_t)` to the `malloc` request, and use those first bytes of the returned allocation to store `sz`. In `operator delete`, you do the reverse: you look for the `sizeof(size_t)` bytes preceding `ptr`.

So the bit of code you'd get is `memory-=static_cast<size_t*>(prt)[-1];`. The `[-1]` looks scary, I know. One of the few cases where it makes sense.

Comment: This was the perfect solution, even now. Thank you very much. =)

Answer (score -1):

You have a wrong assumption here. `sizeof` pointer return size of a pointer, not size of structure to which it points to. So, no matter what type of structure you allocated (no matter if it's `int`, an instance of a class or an array), you always subtract the same amount of memory.

You should check size of the structure to which pointer points to, but it's quite hard in this code. Since you pass `void*` as the argument, you can't dereference it, and you have to idea what type is that pointer.
I suppose you could try with template function to retain pointer type (and be able to dereference it).

Comment: True, how could I missed that? Guess I have to rethink the delete operator overloading.

Comment: Actually, you have a very good idea what type the pointer has. It's whatever you returned from `operator new`. You're missing the point of the `operator new/operator delete` pair; they go hand in hand.

Comment: @MSalters hmm... I guess I could change the line in new operator to     memory+= sizeof(std::malloc(sz)) instead of memory+= sz

Comment: @DerekJohnson: You could, of course, but `sizeof(malloc)` will be probably be 4 or 8 (32 or 64 bit systems), so effectively you'd be counting the **number** of allocations. That's far easier.