# The sized operator delete[] is never called

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am trying to keep track of how much memory has been allocated in my developments. It is easy to keep track of allocation because the overload of `void *operator new (size_t)` and `void *operator new[](size_t)` allow to track how much is allocated. 
With C++ < C++14, [one can resort to a technique of over-allocating memory to store the size of the allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790824/keeping-track-of-used-memory-with-overloaded-new-and-delete-operator)

Since C++14, there are corresponding `void operator delete(void*p, size_t size)` and `void operator delete[](void*p, size_t size)` that should allow to account accurately for every de-allocation (except for a delete of an incomplete type, which is then left to the implementation).

However, though the first version is being called by g++ where a call to delete a single object is made, I have not found a single compiler calling the second one. Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
size_t currentAlloc;

void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    currentAlloc += size;
    std::cout << "1\n";
    return malloc(size);
}

void *operator new[](size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "3\n";
    currentAlloc += size;
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void *p) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Unsized delete\n";
    free(p);
}

void operator delete(void*p, size_t size) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Sized delete " << size << '\n';
    currentAlloc -= size;
    free(p);
}

void operator delete[](void *p) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Unsized array delete\n";
    free(p);
}

void operator delete[](void*p, std::size_t size) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Sized array delete " << size << '\n';
    currentAlloc -= size;
    free(p);
}

int main() {
    int *n1 = new int();
    delete n1;

    int *n2 = new int[10];
    delete[] n2;

    std::cout << "Still allocated: " << currentAlloc << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -std=c++14 test.C` or `clang++ -std=c++14 test.C`. The result of which outputs for g++:

> 1
>   Sized delete 4
>   3
>   Unsized array delete
>   Still allocated: 40

I was expecting for the sized array delete to be called for the second `delete` and for the last printed value to be 0 instead of 40. clang++ does not call any sized de-allocation and neither does the Intel compiler.

Is my code incorrect in any way? Am I misunderstanding the standard? Or are both g++ and clang++ not following the standard?

Comment: You seem to be assuming `free(p);` in `void operator delete[](void *p) noexcept` doesn't free the whole array.

Comment: Any reasons why you're using `malloc()` and `free()` in preference over `new()` and `delete()` in c++?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't know where you think that? I am not making any assumption about free. I am just trying to keep track of how much memory is currently allocated by my code at any point in time.

Comment: @Michel You are only tracking it in a couple of operators. For example `operator delete(void*)` presumably frees memory but you aren't tracking it there.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "void operator delete[](void*p, std::size_t size) noexcept won't be used when void operator delete[](void *p) noexcept is defined" -- citation needed

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I cannot track what `operator delete(void *)` does unless I do like in the link I posted for pre C++14 code. I want to avoid that extra bit of memory. Also, there is nothing in the standard that says that the sized delete won't be called if the non-sized one is defined. The standard says I believe that the non-sized is called by default when the sized one is NOT defined. So I think it's kind of the reverse of what you said.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I was confused with the class specific operators.

Comment: Try to remove `void operator delete(void *p) noexcept` and see if it helps. Implementations can call it instead of the sized version for arrays of trivial types.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The only reason to call malloc() and free() is because I am writing my own new and delete operators to track memory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I did remove it and it does not help. Just checking that I understood that part of the standard correctly.

Comment: @molbdnilo You are right. I missed that 'non-class and trivially-destructible' part. Please post that as the answer and I'll mark it as correct. It's strange though. I wonder what the motivation is?

Comment: `/Zc:sizedDealloc` doesn't make any difference here, the key quote from MSDN is "The single argument versions are called when the compiler can't determine the size of the object being deallocated", the compiler can't easily determine the size of the array from a raw pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the flag on clang. It does make it behave like g++. But still no sized delete for arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete), which is usually reliable, it's unspecified which version is called "when deleting objects of incomplete type and *arrays of non-class and trivially-destructible class types*" (my emphasis).

It also seems that compilers disable the sized delete by default.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the sized deallocation API isn't to help you track how much memory has been allocated or deallocated, and it can't be used reliably for that anyway. The purpose of the sized deallocation API is to improve the efficiency of memory allocators that support sized deallocations, because it lets the compiler call a sized-deallocation method in some cases which means that the memory allocator doesn't need to look up the size of deallocated pointer when doing the deallocation. Andrei Alexandrescu talks about this a bit in his 2015 CppCon talk about the [std::allocator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U) API.

Most memory allocators provide an API like [mallinfo(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) that let you explicitly query the allocator for statistics about how much memory has been allocated or deallocated; I would recommend reading the documentation for whatever allocator you're using to see how to access these statistics.

The reason you can't use it to track the total size of all deallocations is that in general, the compiler doesn't always know the size of the objects that are begin deleted. Consider for example the following code:

```cpp
char *foo(size_t n) {
    char *p = new char[n];
    // do stuff with p, maybe fill it in
    return p;
}

void bar(char *p) {
    delete[] p;
}

void quux(size_t nbytes) {
   char *p = foo(nbytes);
   bar(p);
}
```

In this case the memory is allocated in one place but deallocated elsewhere, and the information about the size of the allocation is lost at the deallocation site. This specific example is very simple so an optimizing compiler might see through this example if the two functions are located nearby, but in general it is not *guaranteed* that the sized deallocation function will be used, it's something that the compiler *may* do.

Additionally, Clang currently (as of late 2020) does not enable sized deallocations even when compiling with `-std=c++14` or (a later standards version like c++17 or c++20); currently to get it to used sized deallocations you need to add `-fsized-deallocation` to your clang command line.